# C++ - Map iterator access results in segfault

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault

I tried to reformulate the question completely. The situation is as follows :

```
 class Departure {
    private :
      unsigned int supply;

    public : 
     Departure(int);
     ~Departure();
     int getSupply()  {
       return supply;
     };
};


class Route {
    private :
       Departure* departure;
    public :
       Departure& getDeparture() { 
          return *departure;
        };
};

class Plan {
    private :      
       std::map<Route*, double> quantities;
    public :
       void addRoute(Route& rt)  {
          quantities.insert(std::pair<Route*,double>(&rt,0));
        };

       void createSolution() {  
          std::map<Route*, double>::iterator it;    
          for(it = quantities.begin(); it != quantities.end(); ++it) {      
             it->second = it->first->getDeparture().getSupply();                        
           };
};
```

After the routes are added - i have checked, it works OK, i get a segfault which from my trial & error up to now is situated in the `it->first->getDeparture().getSupply()` call. Any explanation why?

Comment: Show us how `quantities` is defined and populated.

Comment: Using pointers in C++ is generally a very bad idea.

Comment: @KerrekSB what? Can you please clarify that last comment?

Comment: You haven't given us enough code to reproduce the bug, but you can narrow things down more. What if you remove one of the arguments from the first approach? Or three?

Comment: i added some more of the code.
@Beta I will do that, but still if it's a problem of iterators in general, I want to get how it works.

Comment: @Lirik: This comes up over and over again on SO. Just hang a round for a few days and I'm sure there'll be a more substantial posting somewhere. Or search through some past posts on the topic. Basically, C++ has better, more idiomatic tools for handling dynamic objects than pointers, and dynamic objects are rarely necessary in the first place.

Comment: @KerrekSB LOL, yah I've seen that, but it's just weird how you said it given that C++ is kinda known for using pointers.

Comment: I believe `quantities` is a property of `Plan`. I see `Plan::addRoute(Route& rt)` takes stack objects which is wrong. rather it should take `heap objects` What will cause a segfault is the object the pointer is pointing is getting out of scope as its a stack variable. however here you are passing `*(new object)` which should be okay.

Comment: @Lirik: "kindof known" is unfortunately a long way from "kindof understood"! :-)

Comment: @Lirik that's only really true for code with legacy elements. Pointers are pretty much obsolete in modern C++ code;   for anybody writing new code in 2012, I'm hard pressed to see where pointers would actually be useful or desirable other than for interfacing with old code.   The new C++11 standard has made C++ an almost completely memory-safe language, to the point now where you're probably more likely to leak resources in Managed languages such as C# and Java than you are in C++ code.  (Unfortunately, unsafe code still gets written because many C++ programmers are still "stuck" in the 1990s)

Comment: @BenC do you happen to have any books/tutorials on that? Cause if that's the actual case I'm trying to learn something obsolete.

Comment: I think it's good to study pointers, if only to understand the concept which underlies the more sophisticated structures, but I seem to be in the minority. Anyway, I still don't see the cause of the segfault and can't reproduce it; I suggest you simplify the code as much as you can.

Comment: The question does not contain enough information for me (and, judging by the other comments, others) to help you solve your problem. Mike Ash has posted a great guide on [Getting Answers](http://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html#guide_begin), which might help you to improve your question.

Comment: @Tobias i tried to reformulate the question, which is actually hard because it's a project i use to improve my knowledge in C++ objects & pointers, and it has got a bit out of hand.

Comment: Sorry, but your question still does not contain enough information. From what you provide I cannot analyze object ownership in your code; I suspect that it is related to this (i.e. a dangling pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess (99% sure) that you are facing a problem of dangling pointers, that is, the pointers to Route and Departure objects are no longer valid when you call createSolution.

The easy fix to that is to not use pointers but instead store the Route and Departure objects as values. There is anyway not much benefit in storing them as pointers, considering that the objects are so small...